# How to iterate through a nested array in elasticsearch with filter script?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to filter for a nested field in elasticsearch. Well, I need to return certain documents depending on certain rules.
To reproduce the error I'm getting, you can be guided by this example:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "group": "fans",
  "user": [
    {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first": "Alice",
      "last": "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

As can be seen, we have an array of objects (nested).

I need to apply a script on the nested field where I can go through the array of users.

For example i tried this:

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "script": {
                "script": {
                  "inline": """
                  def users = doc['user'];
                  for ( int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++ ) {
                    
                  }
                  return true;
                  """
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
{
  ...
          "script_stack" : [
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:90)",
            "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:41)",
            "users = doc['user'];\n                  ",
            "            ^---- HERE"
          ],
          ...
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason" : "No field found for [user] in mapping with types []"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Elasticsearch version 7.7

**Is this possible to do? I have reviewed some answers but it is not clear to me.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested documents are powerful because you retain certain attribute connections but there's the downside of not being able to iterate over them as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833172/8160318).

---

With that being said you could flatten the `users` attributes using the [`copy_to`
feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) like so:

```json
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user__first_flattened": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "user": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "first": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "copy_to": "user__first_flattened"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```json
PUT my-index-000001/_doc/1
{
  "group": "fans",
  "user": [
    {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first": "Alice",
      "last": "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you've got access to the field values and can iterate over them (and possibly use the loop index to help locate/identify the correct 'nested' subdocument, if needed.) This only works under the assumption that you iterate over the field that's represented in **each** nested subdocument so that your loop is not cut short:

```json
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": """
                  def users = doc.user__first_flattened;
                  // users == [Alice, John]
                  for ( int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++ ) {
                    
                  }
                  return true;
                  """
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that we're not doing a `nested` query anymore b/c we're outside of that context and got our flattened field available in the root.

---

It's also worth knowing that you can replace `copy_to` with [`include_in_root`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64244021/8160318) which is equally useful here.

Comment: Your solution es the best. Works for me. Thanks. I had no knowledge about copy_to.

Comment: Good! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

List of nested documents of a given parent document is not available with-in the nested context. Hence 'doc['user']' is giving you the exception in the script. However individual nested document can be accessed as below :

```
GET my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "user",
      "query": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['user.first.keyword']=='John'" // <==== This can be done.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share exactly what operation you want to do ?

Comment: "source": "return doc['user.first.keyword'] == 'John'", not working