# How to sort the result set based on the minimum value of a nested field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to sort the result set on the basis of the minimum value of "priceWithPartialDiscount", which is a field inside a nested field.

Consider the nested field:

```
"children": [
{
    "partialDiscountPercent": 0.0,
    "productId": 497071,
    "price": 200.0,
    "priceWithPartialDiscount": 200.0,
    "partialDiscountAmount": 0.0
},
{
    "partialDiscountPercent": 0.0,
    "productId": 497072,
    "price": 100.0,
    "priceWithPartialDiscount": 100.0,
    "partialDiscountAmount": 0.0
}
],
```

I wrote the code for sort:

```
"sort":[{
   "children.priceWithPartialDiscount":{
      "missing":"_last",
      "mode":"min",
      "nested":{
         "filter":{
            "nested":{
               "path":"children",
               "query":{
                  "range":{
                     "children.price":{
                        "gte":0.0
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "path":"children"
      },
      "order":"asc"
   }
}]
```

, and I expect

```
"sort": [100.0]
```

But surprisingly I see:

```
"sort": [200.0]
```

Did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the 2nd level nested-ness inside of the `filter` because the `path` is already defined in the parent's nested context:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "children.priceWithPartialDiscount": {
        "missing":"_last",
        "mode": "min",
        "nested": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "children.price": {
                "gte": 0
              }
            }
          },
          "path": "children"
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think that 2nd level nested query was messing up your sort values in a non-obvious way.

Comment:  Nice. Hey -- shameless plug -- I'm writing an elasticsearch handbook where I discuss the usage of nested fields in more detail. I'd appreciate if you find 2mins to [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) concretely what you'd like to learn more about. Cheers